# Outlook Web Add-in: Async Function throws error from Office internal Javascript

Tags: office-js, outlook-web-addins

When fetching body content of mail using body.getAsync() it throws a `Sys.ArgumentTypeException` error:

> Object of type 'System.Security.Cryptography.CryptoStreamMode' cannot be converted to type 'System.Security.Cryptography.CryptoStreamMode'.

We have tried searching for the error but didn't find any lead yet.

Further investigating we found that generally it works fine but occurs randomly when sending mail (On send Feature). [This is a screenshot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SMxSZ.png)

Edit : 
Following is the confirmed scenario where this error occur :

Step 1) Fetch Item contents in UI less button event like Body,CC,Bcc etc using ASync functions.
Step 2) Open Popup using DialogAPI.

Step 3) Close Popup using cancel button which executes dialog.close() in callback.

Comment: Can you provide more information on the scenario this is failing? Does this only happen on encrypted SMIME messages in OWA?

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT added a scenario which reproduce the issue.

Comment: We are having a hard time reproducing this issue. Could you please clarify, at which step and calling which API you are seeing the exception? Your description is a little confusing - you mentioned you are seeing the exception during body.getAsync(), but you only mention accessing the body in step 1. Are there steps missing? Also it would help if you could provide a simplified set of sources (both HTML so we see which libraries are included and the JS code showing which APIs you're calling and how).

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT If we do not handle the event when click on 'Send' and proceed with any operation it throws the same error. To overcome this we have to open the inspector window ( to make sure that cache is disabled) and then reload the page few times then the error gets resolved.